# PLL in Tracking for GNSS behaviour

Tags: software-defined-radio, pll

[image]I'm doing work on SDR for GNSS and I'm tracking the signals I/Q using PLL. 
The calculations for the PLL is done like the following for error estimation:

```
double PLLAtan::compute(const CorrelationResult &correlation_result)
{
    sampleType I_P = correlation_result.getPromptCorrelator().real();
    sampleType Q_P = correlation_result.getPromptCorrelator().imag();

    double discriminator = static_cast<double>(std::atan(Q_P / I_P)) / (2 * M_PI);
    return discriminator;
}
```

in each epoch time frame:

**pll_fll_filter_.setDiscriminator(pll_disc_->compute(correlation_result));**

My problem is the PLL filter is oscillating between 0.98 to 0.96 and it never locks to 1

Should I do something like accumalting the error in the correllation result from the I/Q calculate the error between last I/Qs and current and use it as input for PLL phase error correction ?

```
    double LoopFilterPLLFLL::updateLoop()
    {
        if(filter_order_ == 2)
        {
            double out_velocity = velocity_integrator_.setInput(w0f_ * fll_discriminator_ + w0_ * w0_ * discriminator_);
            loop_output_        = a2_ * w0_ * discriminator_ + out_velocity;
        }
        if(filter_order_ == 3)
        {
            double out_acceleration
                = acceleration_integrator_.setInput(w0f_ * w0f_ * fll_discriminator_ + w0_ * w0_ * w0_ * discriminator_);
            double out_velocity = velocity_integrator_.setInput(a2_ * w0f_ * fll_discriminator_ + a3_ * w0_ * w0_ * discriminator_
                                                                + out_acceleration);
            loop_output_        = b3_ * w0_ * discriminator_ + out_velocity;
        }
        return (loop_output_);
    }


void LoopFilterPLLFLL::setLoopParameters()
{
    LoopFilter::setLoopParameters(fp_.filter_order_pllfll, fp_.update_rate, fp_.narrow_noise_bandwidth_pll);

    calcLoopParameter(0.0, fp_.wide_noise_bandwidth_fll);
}

void LoopFilterPLLFLL::calcLoopParameter(double pll_noise_bandwidth, double fll_noise_bandwidth)
{
    if(filter_order_ == 2)
    {
        w0f_ = fll_noise_bandwidth / 0.25;
        w0_  = pll_noise_bandwidth / 0.53;
    }

    if(filter_order_ == 3)
    {
        w0f_ = fll_noise_bandwidth / 0.53;
        w0_  = pll_noise_bandwidth / 0.7845;
    }
}
```

Gain Parameters:

```
 "pll": {
                "filter-order": 2,
                "discriminator": "PLL-ATAN",
                "wide-bandwidth": 20,
                "narrow-bandwidth": 5
            },
            "fll": {
                "discriminator": "FLL-DP",
                "wide-bandwidth": 10,
                "narrow-bandwidth": 2
            }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's just the phase discriminator. What does the rest of your PLL do?

Comment: Agree with Marcus; please include a diagram of your complete loop as well as the gain coefficients for each block (counts/radian from your discriminator, radians/count from your carrier recovery phase rotator etc) and what you already understand as to how to design your loop filter and its parameters.

Comment: @DanBoschen I have updated the post, please let me know if you need more information

Comment: If you include a simple control loop block diagram, and show all the gain parameters in that, I can help you! I could probably derive that from all the code you listed, but have minimum time today.

Comment: @DanBoschen Thanks for your help, I just did it from the book above by kaplan

Comment: Please draw up a block diagram of **your actual loop**, not just bits and bobs of things from books that don't even show a whole loop.  Draw it on paper if you must.

Comment: Are you trying to servo the output of your discriminator to zero?  Are you saying the discriminator output is oscillating between 0.98 and 0.96, or that the filter output is oscillating between 0.98 and 0.96?  What is the discriminator output doing?  Is it oscillating wildly, or settled around zero?

Comment: It would be very good for you and for us if you would **express your algorithm in math** (or annotate that block diagram we're asking for with transfer functions).  That way we can see if your *intended* behavior will work; if it should then we can ask why your *code* doesn't match that behavior.  Just dumping 100 lines of code isn't a great help in these situations.

Comment: As Tim said, and this would be very simple but good work on your part--on paper just as he said if you don't have a drawing tool: Draw the Phase Detector as a block and then derive what the transfer function would be in terms of counts/radian, the output from this goes to a loop filter--draw that and whatever you know about it, the output of the loop filter goes to your carrier tracking phase rotator-- this could be an NCO which drives complex multiplier with your incoming signal perhaps but whatever it is you are now controlling to be able to track your carrier - ...

Comment: And then from that work out what is the transfer function for that carrier correction in terms of radians/count (and pay attention to the implied integrator/accumulator that may exist depending on what you are actually using there since for an NCO for example the direct output is in units of frequency not phase--- but complete the sketch and we can help you with that detail).

Comment: I would rewrite your question with that and delete everything you posted -- it greatly simplifies it, shows work you already did and what you understand of that and will be easier for anyone to help you.

Comment: @TimWescott The discriminator output is oscillating between 0.98 and 0.96, I can't drive the transfer function, I'm by no means a DSP expert, so I just implemented what's in the diagram above from the book.

Comment: @TimWescott I just want to know what could be the issue for oscillating ouptput

Comment: @DanBoschen I'm not a DSP expert, can you tell me your ideas on why the PLL output in terms of discriminator is oscillating ?

Comment: You needn’t be an expert- if you proceed with my suggestion we will be able to help you. Does anything with my suggestion confuse you? That is the next step

Comment: Other than that all I can tell you is it isn’t configured right

Comment: @DanBoschen Why would you think it's configured right ? Can you spot the issues please, that's all I needed.

Comment: @DanBoschen I posted the exact loop that I use with Boxcar velocity integrator, that's really what I'm using

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104208/discussion-between-ahmed-saleh-and-dan-boschen).

Comment: Ahmed- is there a reason you don’t want to do what I suggested? I am trying to help you here. I’m out for the rest of the afternoon but if you decide to do just what I suggested I am sure Tim will be able to help you and if not I will tonight. Just posting a generic block diagram with no parameters is of no help. Please read carefully my suggestion. I would really like to help you if you can do that

Comment: @DanBoschen I really implemented it as the block that you see in the picture. I don't know how to configure it, that's my problem, I'm a software engineer, with no experience in DSP and that subject at all

Comment: That picture is just a loop filter—- my request clearly isn’t clear to you. Please make a complete block diagram (sketch it on paper if need be) of your entire loop with the actual parameters you are using not variables. Read my description carefully and let me know if anything in that is confusing you. I would delete everything else in your question as this would simplify it for you and everyone.

Comment: @DanBoschen I wanna tell you the truth, I don't know how to draw the full cycle diagram, the code was there, and I just use it, and as you see it implements the loop filter as shown in the figures, the phase error is just tan I/Q, that's all I understand. If you can deduce the block diagram of the code, I would be very gratefull

Comment: We can’t it really depends on those things I am asking— you would need to have those transfer functions in order to intelligently proceed otherwise you are shooting in the dark. You could do it blindly in iterative stages- google tuning PID filter and you should find the approach (P is the bottom in your diagram; start with setting the others to 0 and bring up P slowly until it oscillates then set it to half that value, then slowly bring up I which is the middle input until it oscillates and then set that to half and then finally bring up D the top input until it is stable.

Comment: But without seeing your diagram I am not confident that Loop Filter will even be hooked up right —- best if you could create the entire diagram I suggest

Comment: @DanBoschen Luckily I have done PID before. On which error that I do the PID on it ? on the PLL Discriminator ? 
Another question, how would I determine the PLL noise bandwidth ?

Comment: Same answer - ideally derive the complete Loop block diagram but you can estimate loop BW experimentally from a step response test. Given your situation I would drop the D and just do a PI loop. You can decide from your requirements and a complete loop model if you need it. It sounds like you may be in over your head and it would be beyond a simple Q&A here.

Comment: (Please don’t take my comment the wrong way)

Comment: @DanBoschen Thanks for your comments. The FLL discriminator is working fine, it jumps from 0 to 1 locked state very fast. but the problem is with the PLL discriminator, it oscillates alot and it never reached a locked state. So I think in the second diagram I will put the PI loop filter on both the PLL error and FLL error. Is that right ?

Comment: (This comment is without seeing the full details so may be misguided) If you have an FLL and it is locking just fine then I would leave the FLL error out completely. Turn down the P and I gains and eventually it should be stable (just very slow to lock). P is the bottom input from phase error that bypasses your integrator, and I is the input that goes through the integrator (accumulator). Start with P and I both equal to 0 and then slowly increase P (With small P it should be stable and eventually lock with small P with a likely large offset error and slow to converge.)

Comment: Increase P from there to find the threshold of instability. Back it off from that point to half it's value --- this is the experimental approach to find the approximate starting value for P. Then slowly increase I to get the desired response time. You can then play with both the P and I values to see there relative effects to come up with final values experimentally.

Comment: @DanBoschen I think I'm missing the inverse Z transform part, but if it's missing why FLL works but PLL doesn't ? If I need inverse of Z transform what would be the equation to it in code ?

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to; did you try what I suggested?

Comment: @DanBoschen I'm still confused, would you write an answer please on which part the PI should be applied, I don't know what what error signal that I should I use, the PLL phase error ?

Comment: See my comment above that starts “P is the bottom input... etc I really don’t have anything more to offer beyond what I said and understood that it doesn’t answer your question

Comment: @DanBoschen So P is like the T in the figure, and I is after a0^2w0 ?

Comment: @DanBoschen Can you look at the output of the PLL please in the post ? I have posted a result picture

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104255/discussion-on-question-by-ahmed-saleh-pll-in-tracking-for-gnss-behaviour).

Comment: @DanBoschen It's never locked the PLL what could be the issue ?

Comment: @DanBoschen can we discuss in chat ?

Comment: Hi @AhmedSaleh I am back at work now and won’t really have time to help you, I am sorry!